# Put computer in hibernate when power outage happens

Tags: windows-10, power, hibernate, ups

I have a Cyberpower UPS connected to my desktop PC. I would like the computer to automatically go into hibernation after a couple minutes of a power failure (i.e. UPS switching to its battery). The UPS is connected to the PC through a USB cable. I installed Power Panel Personal Edition but the options are limited and most are greyed out.

[image: screen shot]

Is there a way to configure this? I'm running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

[The manufacturer's page](https://www.cyberpowersystems.com/products/software/pppe-windows-software) claims that the software (PowerPanel Personal Edition) provides an auto-shutdown function on power loss.

However if you insist on hibernating, you'd have to develop an app, or a PowerShell script that listens to UPS system events (using e.g. WMI), and initiates hibernation. Have a look at [this site](http://www.servercare.nl/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=102) for a sample script (it's from 2011 - I'm sure you can find something more current).

Comment: "The manufacturer's page claims..." I'm calling bs. Did you see the screen shot where it's grayed out?

Comment: Have you tried calling their support?

Comment: You can call "bs", but you're wrong. The screen shot shows "Keep Computer Running" and "Preserve Battery Power". BOTH options offer to shutdown the computer under different circumstances. The UI is coded so that the item that doesn't have the option button is the one that's "grayed". It doesn't mean it's unavailable, it means it's not selected.

Comment: @Jazimov It all looks disabled to me, both radio buttons and dropdowns. Maybe this feature is not available with this UPS model?

Comment: Oh, I can explain. First, I thought Celeritas was talking about the screen shot on the manufacturer's web page... Second, now I realize it's the one posted above (in this thread). It is grayed out only because it is in Run mode. To enable those option buttons, you need to configure the app. I have modified my answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I see two parts to this question:
1) Why are the items grayed-out and how do you enable them?
2) Does PowerPanel support hibernation?

**Why are the items grayed-out and how do you enable them?**
This is terrible software design, and the people who wrote it should be required to listen to repeated plays of Disney's "It's a Small World" song in a locked room for one week.

To enable the options in the application, you have to find the green "P" icon in the system tray and right-click it. Then you need to choose the Configuration option, which requires Windows Administrator privileges:

[image]

**Does PowerPanel support hibernation?**
Well, the PowerPanel Personal Edition online help says this about hibernation:

> Hibernation Enabling
>
> If the hibernation is supported and is not enabled on your computer,
>   the Enable Hibernation on your computer shortcut will be displayed for
>   users to determine whether to enable hibernation. Click the shortcut
>   and then the Confirm Hibernation Enabling message will ask whether to
>   enable the hibernation or not. Click Yes button to enable the
>   hibernation, or click No button not to enable the hibernation. It is
>   recommended that the hibernation should be enabled to avoid the data
>   loss.
>
> Note: If hibernation is disabled or not supported, the computer will
>   be initiated a shutdown.

However, I could never get the link to appear on my Windows 10 Enterprise system even though hibernation was enabled in my OS configuration's Power settings (in Control Panel). I cannot believe the company won't fix this--the software seems to be entirely neglected by the CyberPower folks who make it.

But at least they offer an alternative: The free CyberPower PowerPanel Business Edition (I'm running the latest version, 3.23). That program offers hibernate as a shut-down option before the backup battery power is depleted.